# How to display Google Fusion Table map search result attributes

Tags: google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I am creating a map with Google Fusion Tables that will allow me to search for a local food product and display on a map the retailer that carries it.  Along with showing on the map the location of the retailer, I would like to list in a text box beside the map, other attributes associated with the food product, such as grower, whether it is organic or not, etc.

I have the map and the search function created but have not been able to find example code for displaying the search results in a list beside the map.

Does anyone know of a snippet of example code that will do this?  Or any other tips?

Thanks so much!

Comment: http://locations.weconnectchicago.org/#/?filter_type=Chicago%20Housing%20Authority&view_mode=map&training=1&wifi=1 is a good example of training centres in Chicago (wifi or not etc) as tick boxes